# Trigger mat-selct selectionChange. , when updating form through patchValue

Tags: angular

I am using angular reactive form. There is a mat-select i am using, which is having `selectionChange` event.

When i am updating the form through `patchValue`, this `selectionChange` event is not getting called. Not sure what to do. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the selectionChange is only trigered when it gets a user interaction.

This is the Material Select API description:

> @Output() selectionChange: EventEmitter
>
> Event emitted when the selected value has been changed by the user.

You will need to find another way to use the selectionChange.

If you show your code, maybe I can help you.